# How to set weight for width and height?

Tags: android, view, height, width, android-layout-weight

I need to create view dynamical with width and height which are the percent of parent size.So I need to add weight for width and height for one view. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Yes. I tried to put it in Linear Layout(horizontal) with weight for width and then in Linear Layout(vertical) with weight for height. But I think it is not very good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, I have the below layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_forImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_forList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>    
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I will set width and height for each View depend on Screen width and Screen Height.

```
int screenWidth = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp);
int screenHeight = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenHeightDp);
int ratioW = ....;//
int ratioH = ....;//
setLayoutSize(ll_forImage, screenWidth/ratioW , screenHeight/ratioH );
setLayoutSize(ll_forList, screenWidth/ratioW , screenHeight - screenHeight/ratioH );
// You can use setTranslation to translate View to expected position.
```

with:

```
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}

private static void setLayoutSize(View view, int width, int height) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imgtype"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/txtsubject"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/lat_sub_text_size"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
<LinearLayout/>
```

here you will be able to divide the major portion of parent linearlayout's width to the textview and remaining minor part for imageview this is for aligning horizontally the same can be done for vertical as well.Weightsum property of parent decides number of parts it will contain.

Answer (score 1):

Adding layout_weight is a good approach while using LinearLayout.
Remember, layout_weight works only in case of LinearLayout and cannot be used with RelativeLayout.